# Using uuid for edit/delete in CRUD

Tags: cakephp

- CakePHP 4.4.14
- friendsofcake/crud: 6.2.0

For simply security reasons and also not to reveal the amount of rows in the table I want to use the `uuid` field for the `edit/delete` actions.

Usually it works like this `/edit/123`. This is exactly what I **don't want to have**. Therefore I want to change it to `/edit/446a1a76-4eac-4b2d-8825-7e3a7e91f4a0`.

Yep, and now I get the error message that it cannot be converted to number; this is correct, because `uuid` is not a number.

I checked the events but there is - [also according to the CRUD documentation](https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions/edit.html#crud-beforefind) - the `WHERE` already set.

> **query** A `Query` object from the `Repository` where `$PrimaryKey => $IdFromRequest` is already added to the conditions.

How can I set/change the field in the query to `uuid`. As I understand it, it must be done *before* `beforeFind` because the type for the parameter is already set to `integer` and `uuid` is not an integer.

```
    $this->Crud->on('beforeFind', function(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event) {
        $event->getSubject()->query->where(['uuid' => "uuid-as-string]);
    });
```

Doesn't work because the condition is **added** and the `id` remains in the query.

---

***To make it clear***: Each table has the primary key `id` - according to the CakePHP rules - but each table has also the field `uuid` which is used for public access. Internally the project uses the `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AppController`:

```
public function edit()
{
    ...

    $controllerName = $this->getName();
    $this->getTableLocator()->get($controllerName)->setPrimaryKey("uuid");

    ...
}
```

Then, in the beginning of the CRUD `actions`| `edit` | `view` handler the `id` field  should be re-established as the primary key. This is for example then needed, when the rows of dependent tables are shown in the `edit` mode as well - implemented for example with register tabs.

If `id` won't be set in the beginning then the dependent rows are not found because CakePHP *thinks* `uuid` is the primary key, which isn't.

```
<ControllerInstance>->getTableLocator()->get(<ControllerName>)->setPrimaryKey("id");
```

Comment: It would seem much simpler to just use a uuid *or* an id field, not try to do both, but I know that sometimes system requirements don't lend themselves well to clean technical solutions.

Comment: @GregSchmidt As mentioned, `id` is not an option at all. It can be used internally, but not for privacy relevant applications. I find the combination of `uuid` & `id` as the best solution because each time a row has to be published, `uuid` - which is already in the row - can be used. Internally all SQL commands use the faster `id`. I am anyway wondering why CakePHP doesn't offer an option which allows to set another field for the row select and keeping the 'id` for the joins.

Comment: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-expose aims at sth similar, however this was never used in combination with Crud plugin afaik.

Comment: @mark Thank you. I find so funny your remarks regarding your motivation as they meet also mine. Therefore I wonder even more, that CakePHP doesn't offer something similar out of the box. Thx